# Network adapter worked initially, but not the second time

Tags: networking, drivers

I am running Ubuntu Core QT-Embedded on a nanoPi Neo using [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MXD2T5G) network adapter.

The first time I used the network adapter it worked perfectly. I saw the adapter when I typed `ifconfig -a` and it connected to my network when I typed the following commands:

```
ifdown wlan0 
ifup wlan0
```

But now it doesn't work.

I tested it out on my Windows machine and the adapter works fine, and when I type `lsusb` I can see a network adapter so I'm very confused.

How can I resolve this issue?